# Writing a custom bootstrap table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've a requirement where I need to write a bootstrap table as shown in the picture:

[image: img]
I wrote a code [like this.](http://jsfiddle.net/yx6kwwjs/1/)
**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-center table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <th class="text-center" width="30%">Modules</th>
        <th class="text-center" width="70%">Previlages</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But this doesn't satisfy requirements. How can I create custom table as shown in picture?

Comment: YOu have to use colspan & rowspan to merge the cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-center table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Modules</th>
      <th class="text-center" colspan="4">Previleges</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Add</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th>View</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>User</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Question</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-center table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <th class="text-center">Modules</th>
        <th class="text-center" colspan="4">Previlages</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Add</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
            <td>XYZ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

--EDIT--
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/yx6kwwjs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered text-center table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <th class="text-center" width="30%">Modules</th>
        <th colspan="4" class="text-center" width="70%">Previlages</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
            <td>Update</td>
            <td>New</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Like this it should be

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't satisfy requirements completely. Please check the picture

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-center table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <th class="text-center" width="30%">Modules</th>
        <th colspan="4" class="text-center" width="70%">Previlages</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Add</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
            <td>View</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>User</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```